# Lenovo Thinkpad T560 Sim Card Not recognized on Debian 9

Tags: linux, debian, thinkpad

I use a Lenovo T560 laptop with Debian 9 Linux desktop operating system. This laptop already has an integrated SIM-card slot and WWAN hardware is present.
Unfortunately, my device (Debian 9) doesn't recognize my SIM-card on network manager. How can I fix this? Command output is below:

`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:0017 Validity Sensors, Inc. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:0706 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`usb-devices`

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh=12
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.18
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.18.0-kali2-amd64 xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=045e ProdID=0745 Rev=06.76
S:  Manufacturer=Microsoft
S:  Product=Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v8.0
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=06 Cnt=02 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=0a2b Rev=00.01
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=e0(wlcon) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=btusb

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=07 Cnt=03 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=5986 ProdID=0706 Rev=00.12
S:  Manufacturer=SunplusIT Inc
S:  Product=Integrated Camera
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=08 Cnt=04 Dev#=  5 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=11 Prot=ff MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=138a ProdID=0017 Rev=00.78
S:  SerialNumber=7a3f29ab69b1
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 4 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=5000 MxCh= 6
D:  Ver= 3.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=03 MxPS= 9 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0003 Rev=04.18
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.18.0-kali2-amd64 xhci-hcd
S:  Product=xHCI Host Controller
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:14.0
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

`systemctl status ModemManager`

```
● ModemManager.service - Modem Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ModemManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-02-17 09:37:50 EST; 23min ago
 Main PID: 518 (ModemManager)
    Tasks: 3 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 8.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/ModemManager.service
           └─518 /usr/sbin/ModemManager --filter-policy=strict
```

Comment: Did you load Lenovo/Thinkpad-specific modules?

Comment: specific modules  like what ?

Comment: On my Thinkpad-cum-Ubuntu (P50) I have a `thinkpad_acpi` module. Thinkpads are Ubuntu-certified, but Ubuntu comes with proprietary drivers that may be missing in a bare-bones Debian.

Comment: oh is it , ok  so what should i do now, what drivers i should install ? guide me in steps pls

Comment: The only answer I can give you is to try booting a live Ubuntu and test with that.